# can't add content to custom table view cell in view controller in IB

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, xcode5

I want to customize a prototype cell in a `UITableView` which is part of an `UIViewController`. Usually labels are drawn from the library to the cell but it doesn't work with this embedded `UITableView` cell. So, how do I customize the prototype cell via IB in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, I think the problem is a glitch. Click your TableView then change the content type to "Static Cells", drag in a label and then switch back to dynamic.

Comment: I aggree, it looks like a bug. Let me check your proposal out. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, I've run into this a couple times :)